# Trying to catch DbEntityValidationException but skips straight to general exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Note:  this is with EF6

I am adding several dozen each of 3 or 4 different types of entities before calling savechanges.  When I do, Im catching an exception where the inner exception message indicates "string or binary data will be truncated".  Its pretty obvious that one of the fields is trying to put a string into a field of one of the tables that isnt large enough to hold it.  The question is - which field.  One of the tables has 30-40 fields.

Sometimes while debugging, if there is an FK constraint error, I will see EntityValidationErrors in the locals window.  In this case I do not.

So I am trying to specifically catch any EF errors so as to identify the culprit, but in the code below, it skips straight to the catch on the general exception.

```
        //were done
        try
        {
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }

        catch(DbEntityValidationException ef)
        {
            retval = -1;
            throw ef;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            retval = -1;
            throw ex;
        }
```

How can I identify which field/entity is causing this issue?

Comment: I would guess it's probably *not* throwing a DbEntityValidationException.  What type of exception is `ex`?

Comment: You could handle the `System.Data.DataException`.Use the debugger to look at the type of the exception.

Comment: That helped, because when it hit I was able to see the InnerException, which had hanging off of it the StateEntries property.  This contained 1 item of type EntityEntry and drilling down a bit further I was able to see the culprit string.  thank you!  You should reply with this as an answer.